# How can I bind a command in a user control?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, ioc-container, structuremap

## **Introduction**

I am trying to cover my C# WPF application into an MVVM pattern using Structuremap IoC container for dependency injection.

My code is works well until I try to use the same command binding in UserControls as Windows.

## **I tried the following**

If I try to bind a command in a certain UserControl, I got the following error: `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'HelloWorldCommand' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindowViewModel' (HashCode=7304143)'. BindingExpression:Path=HelloWorldCommand; DataItem='MainWindowViewModel' (HashCode=7304143); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')`

So the problem is that my `HelloWorldCommand` is it in my `CustomUserControlViewModel` which contained and binded by `MainWindowViewModel`.

## **My custom code snippet**

My code is 90% same to the following tutorial:
[Part 1](https://developerhandbook.com/wpf-mvvm/wpf-mvvm-ioc-containers-1-of-2/)
[Part 2](https://developerhandbook.com/wpf-mvvm/wpf-mvvm-ioc-containers-2-of-2/)

Only the ObjectFactory method is different, which can be seen below:

```
public sealed class ObjectFactory
    {
        public static IContainer Container { get; private set; }

        private static Action<ConfigurationExpression> _initialiseMethod;
        private static readonly Lazy<IContainer> _containerBuilder =
            new Lazy<IContainer>(CreateContainer, LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);

        public static void Initialise()
        {
            Container = _containerBuilder.Value;
        }

        private static IContainer CreateContainer()
        {
            return new Container(config =>
            {
                #region services
                config.For<IFileDisplayerService>().Singleton().Use<FileDisplayerService>();
                config.For<IWatermarkService>().Singleton().Use<WatermarkService>();
                #endregion

                #region windows
                config.For<IWindow>().Use<MainWindow>();
                config.For<IWatermarkWindow>().Use<WatermarkSettingsWindow>();

                config.For<IMainWindow>().Singleton().Use<MainWindow>();
                config.For<IMainWindowViewModel>().Singleton().Use<MainWindowViewModel>();

                config.For<IWatermarkSettingsWindow>().Singleton().Use<WatermarkSettingsWindow>();
                config.For<IWatermarkSettingsWindowViewModel>().Singleton().Use<WatermarkSettingsWindowViewModel>();
                #endregion

                #region views
                config.For<IFileListView>().Use<FileListView>();
                config.For<IFileListViewModel>().Use<FileListViewModel>()
                    .Ctor<IView>().Is<FileListView>();

                config.For<IFileDisplayerView>().Use<FileDisplayerView>();
                config.For<IFileDisplayerViewModel>().Use<FileDisplayerViewModel>()
                    .Ctor<IView>().Is<FileDisplayerView>();
                #endregion
            });
        }
    }
```

## **My question**

My concrete question is that how can I bind a command to a user control which has an own- and a parent ViewModel? This is not shown in the example above.

I think the parent ViewModel should contain the command as well, but I don't know how can I pass it to the parent ViewModel from child ViewModel.

Comment: *"My code is 90% same to the following tutorial"* means your code is *different*. Please share the relevant portions of your code, right here in your question. *"I think the parent ViewModel should contain the command as well, but I don't know how can I pass it to the parent ViewModel from child ViewModel"* -- I doubt that's a good idea, but the parent viewmodel can, if it wants, grab any property it wants from its own child -- unless you're hiding its own children from it with some byzantine IOC thing, in which case you've learned a new reason not to use those.

Comment: Show us [the actual code, XAML and C#, which produced the errors you're getting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As the error suggests you do not have a property called `HelloWorldCommand` on your `MainWindowViewModel`. Given that the `DataContext` of your `UserControl` appears to be pointing to the `MainWindowViewModel` the property should **only** be defined there.

Comment: @Bijington got the point. "... MainWindowViewModel the property should only be defined there.". So the target is to correctly separating the parts from each other. This means that I want to implement the UserControl's button in the UserControl's ViewModel and not in the parent Window's ViewModel.

My next idea is that somehow mergeing the child's dataContext with the parent's dataContext programatically. Is it feasible?

Tomorrow I'll upload my whole code to an illustrative git repo, but now unfortunately this is all I have.

Comment: Is `CustomUserControlViewModel` a property of `MainWindowViewModel`? Then you could bind to a property of like this: `{Binding CustomUserControlViewModel.HelloWorldCommand}`. But you should post the definition of your classes and clarify what the DataContect of the command is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you mm8 I solved my problem like the following mode:

MainWindowViewModel:

```
public IViewModel FileListViewModel { get; set; }
public IViewModel FileDisplayerViewModel { get; set; }

public IView FileListView { get; set; }
public IView FileDisplayerView { get; set; }

public MainWindowViewModel(IWindow window, IContainer container,
        IFileDisplayerViewModel fileDisplayerViewModel, IFileListViewModel fileListViewModel) : base(window, container)
        {
            FileListViewModel = fileListViewModel;
            FileListView = FileListViewModel.View;

            FileDisplayerViewModel = fileDisplayerViewModel;
            FileDisplayerView = FileDisplayerViewModel.View;
        }
```

Now I can bind my UserControl's ViewModel into UserControlView:

```
<Button Command="{Binding FileListViewModel.HelloWorldCommand}" Width="100" Height="20" Content="Push" Background="White"></Button>
```

This is not entirely what I wanted but it saves me from catastrophic spaghetti code. I think it is feasible that I have a child view collection which is used to automatically bind a command from them if it is not available in the parent view. But this is sufficient now to proceed the project. Thank you!